# Using IF OR function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what I was trying (clearly not working)

```
=IF(OR(C22="Positive",C23="Positive"),"0",(=min(C20:C21)))
```

What I'm trying to do is if either `C22` or `C23` comes out as `Positive` (doesn't matter which), then the Final Score will be populated as a `0`.  However, if both `C22` and `C23` are `Negative`, then it will take the lower score from `C20:C21`

[image: Functional Movement Screen Spreadsheet]

Comment: Delete `=` before `min` and brackets `()` around it..

Comment: =IF(OR(C22 > 0 ,C23 > 0),0,MIN(C20:C21))

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(OR(C22>0,C23>0),0,MIN(C20:C21))
```